# Unity ResolveAll not working

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am using Unity for the first time. I am trying to add some dependencies in code, but they are not getting resolved. Code below:

```
    public interface IClassA
    {
        void Show();
        void ShowCount();
        int ID { get; set; }
    }

    class ClassA  : IClassA
    {
        public int count = 0;

        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.ToString());
        }

        public void ShowCount()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(count++);
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Following code is using Unity:

```
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        InjectionMember[] members1 = {new InjectionProperty("ID", 10)};
        InjectionMember[] members2 = {new InjectionProperty("ID", 20)};

        container.RegisterType(typeof(IClassA), typeof(ClassA), members1);
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IClassA), typeof(ClassA), members2);

        foreach(var x in container.ResolveAll<IClassA>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.ID);
        }
```

What is missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use named mappings if you want to register diffrent mappings for a type. Currently you have only one default unnamed mapping, that you override with this calls

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IClassA), typeof(ClassA), members1);
container.RegisterType(typeof(IClassA), typeof(ClassA), members2);
```

To solve it you need to give the mappings a name

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IClassA), typeof(ClassA), "Mapping1", members1);
container.RegisterType(typeof(IClassA), typeof(ClassA), "Mapping2", members2);
```

The call `ResolveAll<IClassA>` will then return all named mappings of the type, but not the default unnamed mapping (if you registered one).

For more information see also [Registering Types and Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660923%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)